# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation Single View

Tags: objective-c

How can I set which orientations my single view should do?
This one below works giving me all the orientations, but in specific view, I dont want to rotate.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 return YES;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     //Or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Yea, but when I do this, it applies for each view in TabBar.

Comment: Please explain your problem more thoroughly.

Comment: I have a TabBar with 4 views, ok? I set my app to rotate in all orientations. But in one of these views, i need to lock rotation. When I return shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method to YES, it rotates in ALL views.

Comment: Then just do a check in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in your main view. Check which tabbar item is selected. If it's what you want to lock, lock its orientation.

Comment: I tried it, and didnt work. It even works if I declare the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation on app delegate.